# Angular, ngModel, and Dragon Voice

Tags: angularjs, voice-recognition, angular-ngmodel

Im working on an Angular powered application that is adding Dragon voice recognition, and when using Dragon's 'Spell' command to enter text inside a text box, the ngModel for the text control does not update.

How can I get ngModel for the control to update the model when using voice recognition so our application behaves as expected for both voice and non-voice users?

Note:the application is currently using angular v1.2.x

Comment: You probably need to wrap that functionality inside a Directive (which is the only place where DOM manipulation should happen as per AngularJS patterns).  It would be useful if you could share a code portion to better suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging into ng-model a bit more, I found that ngModel for text based <inputs> does not update the [ngModleControllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) `$viewValue` when a [Composition Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CompositionEvent) is in progress (this is triggered by Dragon when it is in 'Spell' mode). I later found [ngModelOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) and tried to use it, but this commits changes to `$viewValue` and not changes from the actual <input>.

For our scenario, the user would normally press the 'enter' key to submit the contents of the text box, so we created the following directive to resolve our situation

```
directive('sqEnter', ['$timeout',function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var composing = false;
            element.on('compositionstart', function (data) {
                composing = true;
            });

            element.on('compositionend', function () {
                composing = false;
            });

            element.on('keydown keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.which === 13) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                if (composing) {
                    element.trigger('compositionend');
                    $timeout(handler, 5);
                }
                else handler();                    
            }
        });
        function handler() {
                scope.$apply(function () {
                    scope.$eval(attrs.sqEnter);
                });
            }                            
        }
    }
}]);
```

Usage: `<input type='text' ng-model='myValue' sq-enter='doSomething()' />`.

The important thing here was triggering the `compositionend` event when appropriate so the model updates properly.